# То работает то не работает className в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

есть два сервера и два идентичных (переносилось методом создания архива всех сорцов и распаковки) проекта. В одном строка не выдает ошибку,в другом - выдает:
вот код: if `($this->getModule()->className === null) {...}`
Вот ошибка: `Getting unknown property: rico\yii2images\Module::className`
версия пхп 7.0.22 на обоих серверах.

Comment: попробуйте версию php 5.6 поставить

Comment: стоит php 7. проблема решилась обновлением фреймворка с версии 2.0.5 до последней..

Answer (score 0):

проблема решилась обновлением yii фреймворка с версии 2.0.5 до последней